# Performance difference between "int a, b;" and "int a; int b;"?

Tags: c++, c, compilation, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

It's an easily described in question as the title says.

This question came to my mind every time I can put two separate statements together in a block. Especially when I code for CPU cost problems like NP-complete problems.

Is there any, necessary to combine two separate statements together?.

Comment: No difference to *runtime* at all. Possibly a small hit at compile time but negligible.

Comment: None.  This is a _style_ issue - not a performance one.  Follow your group's coding guidelines. Consider also asking "Is there any necessary to **not** combine two separate statements?"

Comment: Both are noop since `int` type does not require initialization.

Comment: The compiler will generate exactly the same code for both (if it generates any at all). Most likely those instructions will simply tell the compiler how much memory to set aside for the actuall instructions that use the variables later on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Performance difference between “int a, b;” and “int a; int b;”?

Those declarations are semantically equivalent, and there is no reason why either would generate different program from the other, and therefore no reason why there would be difference in performance.

However, the first declaration is shorter by a few characters, so the compilation process might be a few micro-seconds faster for the time that's needed to load the source file from the disk.

> Is there any necessary to combine two separate statements together?

In general, no.

Comment: Related: [CPP core guideline: Declare one name (only) per declaration](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#es10-declare-one-name-only-per-declaration)

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, both are equivalent declarations.  One may compile slightly faster than the other.

They are both *declarations*.
Declarations can be implemented at run-time by allocating space in memory (such as on the stack), reserving a register, or ignored.

If the compiler emits instructions for the variable allocations, the processing time will be negligible (in the order of nanoseconds or microseconds).

In considering performance, your first check list item should be (in the following order):

1. Requirements - Elimination of requirements can speed up a program.
2. Design - Efficient algorithms, removal of variables, efficient
   interfaces
3. Implementation (coding) - Efficient coding of algorithms.
4. Compiler Optimization levels -- Setting compiler optimization levels
   at their highest.
5. Platform specific tricks -- Using special processor algorithms,
   hardware support, etc.

Usually, customers would rather have a slower higher quality program than a really fast unreliable program.
Stakeholders would rather have a program developed quicker than paying for optimizations that don't have a high Return On Investment (ROI).

Focus on quality and robustness.  Optimize only when necessary.